# How do I refresh data when I hit Tab on the left in magento2

Tags: magento2, admin, tabs, page-layouts

When developing editing pages of background management pages, currently magento2 does not refresh the data when switching different Tab pages. I want to refresh the page data when switching tabs. What should I do?
Below are my layout file contents.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magenest\Hotel\Block\Adminhtml\Features\Edit" name="hotel_features_edit"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <uiComponent name="hotel_services_listing"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
<referenceContainer name="left">
    <block class="Magenest\Hotel\Block\Adminhtml\Features\Edit\Tabs" name="hotel_features_tabs">
        <block class="Magenest\Hotel\Block\Adminhtml\Features\Edit\Tab\Features" name="hotel_features_tab_general"/>
        <block class="Magenest\Hotel\Block\Adminhtml\Features\Edit\Tab\Services" name="hotel_services_tab_general"/>
        <action method="addTab">
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">hotel_features_general</argument>
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">hotel_features_tab_general</argument>
        </action>
        <action method="addTab">
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">hotel_services_general</argument>
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">hotel_services_tab_general</argument>
        </action>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: That's not enough data, put your code, screenshot for better understanding

Comment: I added the layout file code,  thank you